# How to make banner images adjust to different size screen?

Tags: jquery, responsive, banner

Now I have a image 1920*628px. My computer screen is 1366*768px，how to make the banner images to adjust to different size screens?Is there any proper solutions to solve this problem?

Comment: Which way you want to make it responsive? by css or jquery ?

Comment: @AmbrishPathak, Either, I'd like to learn more solutions about this problem:)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple approaches to make a image responsive.

### css way

> Adding max-width:100% and height:auto will make images flexible
>
> For IE8 you need to add
> `width:auto\9`

```
Responsive-img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* for ie8 */
}
```

Any image with the class `.Responsive-img` will auto adjusted wrt container.

### css 3 way

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1440px) {
    /* styles for 1440 px sized screens and larger */
}
```

Similarly other css 3 media queries.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    /* styles for wide screens */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    /* styles for mobile devices or narrow screens */
}
```

For more info on Css 3 media queries refer [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)

### Using jQuery plugin `Responsive Img`

Include plugin in the web page

```
<script src="js/responsiveImg.js"></script>
```

Then

```
$("img").responsiveImg();
```

More info about this plugin is here -  [Responsive Img](http://responsiveimg.com/)

Answer (score 0):

It quite simple, if you mean window size, by using @media

```
.picture{
        width:100%;
        height: auto;
}
@media (max-width: 1920px) {
   .picture {
       width: 1920px;
       height: 1080px;
    }
 }

 @media (max-width: 1366px) {
    .picture {
       width: 1366px;
       height: 768px;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Is this right? When(max-width: 1920px){ .picture {
       width: 1366px;
       height: 768px;
    } } and when (max-width: 1366px) ,the picture size is also 1366px * 768px?

Comment: Yes this is right, just replace with sizes you need